# Access Travel Distance from BING Routes API XML Response

Tags: php, xml, routes, bing, bing-api

--answered, see below--

How does one access and echo the **Travel Distance** amount from the Bing Routes API response?

There are many tutorials on XML: http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Here is an example of the response (travel distance is near the bottom): 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg636957.aspx

Here is an example of code to call the response and retrieve Travel Distance.

```
$calculateURL = $drivingRoutesBaseURL."?wayPoint.1=".$waypoint1."&wayPoint.2=".$waypoint2."&output=xml&key=".$bingKey;
```

//send request
  // get the response from the Locations API and store it in a string

```
$output = file_get_contents($calculateURL);
```

// create an XML element based on the XML string,

```
$response = new SimpleXMLElement($output);
```

//get travel distance element from response

```
$travelDistance = $response->ResourceSets->ResourceSet->Resources->Route->TravelDistance;

echo $travelDistance;
```

Answer (score 0):

This line returns object with the travel distance.

```
$travelDistance = $response->ResourceSets->ResourceSet->Resources->Route->TravelDistance;

echo $travelDistance;
```